# How to move an equation in a diagram in iWork Numbers?

Tags: numbers, iwork, macos

I have a diagram in macOS Numbers 12.2.1 with two trendlines where I also inserted the equation for each trendline. The problem is that those two equations are on top of each other and I can't find a way to move them:

[image: diagram with two trendlines and their corresponding equations]

Clicking on them shows that they are selected:

[image]

and I can change e.g. font size when I am in this "mode", but I am unable to move them. If I click, hold and drag I just move the everything, both equations and the actual diagram. No difference if I click and drag the number or the "handles" (the empty circles) Doubleclicking does nothing.

**How do I move the equations?** I want them separated, preferably close to the their corresponding trend line.

---

**Update 1:** Tried removing and re-inserting the trendlines, but the result was the same.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Equations are placed apart from each other when I ask Numbers to place two trend line equations in the same chart. What is your Numbers version? Try "Distribute Objects" in the context menu after selecting both equations and then right-clicking on either. If that does not work, maybe recreating another chart from scratch might help.

Comment: Is this on iPad numbers app?

Comment: @Alper The version is 12.2.1. If I check the ´Show R²` for both these trendlines, the values appear separated from each others, but I still can't move them. When I click an R²-value, it is selected (marked with "rings") but when I drag it, I move the whole graph. However, if I select the "labels" (that explains the different lines in the graph) I can move them (as a group) as expected (and if I double click I can edit them). Can you move your equations and R²-values, one by one or as a group?

Comment: @bmike No, desktop-Numbers

Comment: Thanks. I’ll tag it macOS so people know you have better font choice options than on the web or iPad version of these apps for styling things

Comment: @d-b I can't move any of the equations or any of the R2's or any of them as a group separately from the chart but they all come out somewhere on the top left corner separately and legibly in the first hand. I wonder if the values in your chart and therefore the placement of other elements could be confusing Numbers. Have you tried changing y-axis scales so that there is more space in the chart for Numbers to place the equations? In addition, have you tried a completely different and simpler set of values and see if Numbers can place the equations nicely from the beginning?